# How do I create models to connect with a collection in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying to learn how to create models for collections to connect with the DB and query data. I know how to do using js via Schema, but in python I am unable to find the documentation. I am using pymongo here.

Can someone please let me know how to create a model in python?

Comment: I don't think there is an equivalent to mongoose for pymongo and not sure why you would want it. You can check out the [tutorial in the docs](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) for examples of connecting and interacting via pymongo.

Comment: OK I get it, thanks for the response!